# querySelectorAll not working?

Tags: javascript, html

this is my javascript code:

```
function answer(){
var list = document.querySelectorAll("#fish");
list[1].onclick = talk();
}

function talk(){
alert('hello!');
}

window.onload = answer();
```

on run it pops my browser window with alert: 'hello'.
my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>my site</title>
<script src="new 3x.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<section>
<p id="fish">hello world!</P>
<p id="fish">tuna</P>
<p id="stuff">durr</P>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

it alerts hello on loading the tab.whereas i want it to run alert when i click tuna!

Comment: `id` should be unique.

Comment: Just to clear it up for anyone thinking "oh my god duplicated IDs": yes it's bad HTML. No it won't break querySelectorAll: https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#id-selectors says: "It is possible in non-conforming documents for multiple elements to match a single ID selector."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not assigning event handlers correctly - you're assigning the *result* of invoking your functions, rather than the functions themselves. Remove the `()`s:

```
function answer(){
var list = document.querySelectorAll("#fish");
list[1].onclick = talk;
}

function talk(){
alert('hello!');
}

window.onload = answer;
```

What's currently happening is that, as soon as the `window.onload = answer();` line is hit, you're immediately running the `answer` function. It, in turn when it reaches the `onclick` line, is immediately invoking the `talk` function. That's not what you wanted.

Comment: i removed parenthesis and now its not executing alert at all

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IDs why use querySelectorAll in the first place? Just use getElementById.

```
var list = document.getElementById("fish");
list.addEventListener('click', talk, false);
```

**EDIT**

Now i see you are using non-unique IDs, what in my opinion is bad practice. Why not just use the class `fish` ?

```
<p class="fish">hello world!</P>
<p class="fish">tuna</P>
<p id="stuff">durr</P>
```

Then select like so:

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll(".fish");
list[0].addEventListener('click', talk, false);
```

Comment: If the IDs aren't unique, then just use classes.. ? Bad practice imo not to use unique IDs.

Comment: I've just answered your question "why querySelectorAll?" :)

Comment: Haha fair enough, not trying to be harsh :)